# Upload multiple images into database using laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to upload multiple images and store them into database, but i got an error like this :

```
file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
```

This is my controller :

```
public function fileMultiple(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        if($request->hasfile('filename'))
         {

            foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
            {
                $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image_encod = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('filename')));
                $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
                $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

                $data = new Image();
                $data->image_name = $image_encod;
                $data->save();

            }
         }

        return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been successfully');
    }
```

how to fix it, the image must encode using base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending the array value.

The following code:

```
$image_encod = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('filename')));
```

should be changed into:

```
$image_encod = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply change a little bit in **foreach** loop and use the **$key** by following:

```
foreach($request->file('filename') as $key => $image)
{
   $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
   $image_encod = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('filename')[$key]));
   $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
   $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

   $data = new Image();
   $data->image_name = $image_encod;
   $data->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

public function fileMultiple(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if(is_array($request->filename) && count($request->filename) > 0){

        foreach ($request->filename as $key => $file) {

            if($request->hasFile('filename.' . $key)){

                $file = $request->file('filename.' . $key);

                if($file->store(public_path('/images')))
                {
                    $data = new Image();
                    $data->image_name = $image_encod;
                    $data->save();

                    return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been successfully');
                }
                else{
                    throw new \Exception('Unable to save image.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return back()->with('error', 'Unable to save image.');
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code, and i got error Impossible to create the root directory

Comment: Can you check file permissions of public folder?